# using currval in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to get the `currval` in a where clause ? 
I'm trying to check if the `id = currval`. I've tried the following:

```
insert into order values(   
orderid_seq.nextval,
SYSDATE ,
&quantity, 
&student_number,
&room_number, 
&menu_item ,
(select item_cost  * order_quantity 
FROM order_stock,order
WHERE order_stock.menu_item = 
order.menu_item and 
order_id   =  orderid_seq.currval
));
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that? Which database are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What database is this? If it's Oracle and `orderid_seq` is a sequence, no you can't use sequence methods in a `where` clause.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns002.htm

Comment: its SQL developer

Comment: Which **database**? Oracle have a desktop tool called 'SQL Developer' so I'm going to guess it's Oracle, but a tag would help.

Comment: yeah sorry its oracle

Comment: Thanks. A tag would still help though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IN` if there are many in `orderid_seq.currval`, and the correct syntax is :

```
   select item_cost  * order_quantity 
    FROM order_stock,order
    WHERE order_stock.menu_item = 
    order.menu_item and 
    order_id   IN  (select order_id from orderid_seq.currval)
```

**updated**

```
 select item_cost  * order_quantity 
    FROM order_stock,order
    WHERE order_stock.menu_item = 
    order.menu_item and 
    order_id  =  (select order_id from Your_table where orderid_seq = 'currval')
```

Comment: because there is multiple in orderid_seq.currval, I need it to input value only where the current order_id = currval

Comment: check my updated @alex, and pay attention to William Rovertson 's answer